# How to set correct TypeScript types for a function wrapped with login status check?

Tags: typescript

I want to make a function wrap, that function receive a function B variant.
That received function will make a request. function wrap will return function C when the loginStatus check finish. Below is my implementation.

```js
   const wrap = <Req, Res>(B: (req?: Req, options?: any) => Promise<Res>) => {
        return async (req?: Req, options?: any) => {
            const loginStatus = await loginStatusPromise;
            if (loginStatus) {             return null;           }
            return fun(req, options);
        };<br/>
    };<br/>
```

I try to call wrap function at other place like below:

```js
const fucD = wrap<string, obj>(async (currency: string) => requestfunc({platform: "WEB", currency}));
```

got ts error:

```js
    Types of parameters 'currency' and 'req' are incompatible.
     Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

the currency param is require,I can't set the param to optional.

how should I set the ts type so that the function returned after the wrap function is called has the same received value as the B function, and the return value is the return value of the B function or null.

Comment: Passing type arguments explicitly in function calls such as `wrap<string, obj>(...)` is an error 99% of the time usually stemming from a misunderstanding of type inference and how to obtain type safety. `wrap(...)` is what you want. Type parameters should be inferable from value parameters and in your case they certainly are.

Comment: I need to define `function B` when I define `function wrap`. How can I set the `function B` 's type?

Comment: no you don't need to do that because the function value that are wrapping is already well typed. You shouldn't be specifying type arguments independently of the arguments which they describe.